# Properties showing null in WCF WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a working WCF WebService that is having a bad time parsing some XML values. I have a input object with some properties, and some of this properties show as null, but the client is passing values to these propeties.

On SoapUI:

[image: Properties Nom_Logr_Segurado and Nom_Logr_Cobranca filled with value]

Properties Nom_Logr_Segurado and Nom_Logr_Cobranca filled with value

On Visual Studio 2017 debugging the service:

[image: Only the Nom_Logr_Segurado property have value]

Only the Nom_Logr_Segurado property have value

Both properties have [DataMember] annotation (in fact all properties of input object have). Both have same datatype (string).

Can anyone help? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: The fields on my input XML was in a different order.

By default the .NET shows the parameters in alphabetical order and my XML was not in the correct order.

I changed [DataMember] of each input field to [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = X)] (incrementing the order) and then I adjusted the input XML to respect the same fields order, and how everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark. Is it perhaps a nullable type? Then you have to set ValueSpecified to true before the services receives the value correct.

Grtz,
Miscode